# Delegate fullscreen event AVPlayer objective-c

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, react-native, avplayer

After several sleepless nights, I don't have any more ideas how to do what I am trying to do.

In short words, I am trying to allow my fullscreen video to be accessible in all orientations (landscape and portrait). This is the only place in the app where I want to allow that. All other views are locked to portrait.

My idea was to delegate fullscreen enter / exit event and in that place, programmatically set orientation allowance, so on fullscreen enter, unlock landscape additionally and on fullscreen exit, lock back only to portrait. Everything works fine apart from the one crucial part...I can not delegate fullscreen enter/exit event (delegating those events was my idea but I might be completely wrong and that should be managed in completely different way)

I am using this library: https://github.com/brentvatne/react-native-video

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Let me guess: The video's size, by default, fills the screen in one orientation but not the other.